# Searching for a callback on refresh event with JSTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Look many post here but didn't find what I want.

JSTree version is 3.3.3.

I want to select a node after a create_node event that send an AJAX request.

Then JSTree fire the rename_node event. In this event, I make another AJAX request to rename the category or the article on my database.

Here I need to refresh the tree in order the new node get is correct ID etc...

This make an AJAX call to rebuild nodes with JSON from server side and javascript keep on executing code... :(

So the only solution I found to select my new node is to make a setTimeout to ensure that tree is rebuilt and then I parse my url to select the node like this :

```
//  Select Article or Category newly created
if ( window.location.pathname.split("/")[3] == "edit" ) {
    id = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
    controller = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] == "articles" ? "article_" : "category_"
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#tree').jstree("deselect_all")
        $('#tree').jstree("select_node", controller+id)
    },1500);
}
```

I didn't like that and if ajax request to rebuild node failed or is too long, this will cause an issue.

I have not find callback on refresh event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with a completely different way, select the node at the creation and redirect on article/:id/edit or category/:id/edit

```
    // Create category && articles
    .on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        data_JSON = {}
        if ( data.node.type === "category" ) {
            controller = "categories"
            data_JSON = { parent_id :  data.parent.match(/\d+/)[0] } // DRY
        } else {
            controller = "articles"
            data_JSON = { category_id :  data.parent.match(/\d+/)[0] } // DRY
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : "/" + controller + "/new",
            method : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            data : data_JSON
        })
        .done(function (d) {
            data.instance.deselect_all()
            data.node.id_number = d[data.node.type + "_id"]
            data.instance.set_id(data.node.id, data.node.type+"_"+data.node.id_number)
            data.instance.select_node(data.node.id)
            data.node.userCreatedNode = true
        });
    })
    // Rename category && articles
    .on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        controller = data.node.type === "category" ? "categories" : "articles"
        data_JSON = {}
        data_JSON[data.node.type] = { id : data.node.id, title : data.text }
        data.node.id_number===undefined && ( data.node.id_number = data.node.id.match(/\d+/) )
        $.ajax({
            url : "/" + controller + "/" + data.node.id_number,
            method : "PATCH",
            dataType : "json",
            data : data_JSON
        })
        .done( function (d) {
            if ( data.node.userCreatedNode == true ) {
                edit_path = window.location.origin+"/"+controller+"/"+data.node.id_number+"/edit"
                window.location.href = edit_path
            }
        });
    })
```